# bash: change tab title when command is run

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, iterm2

I want to change the tab title in iTerm2 if a specific command is run. Specifically, when the `runserver` command from django is run, I would like the tab to show 'runserver' in the title.

I've been experimenting with bash escape codes, but I can't find something to do this. I have seen `trap` brought up in similar questions, but I can't find great documentation on how to do something like what I want.

iTerm2 also has 'triggers' in preferences that checks for regex matches, but I can't get the 'command' portion to execute. I.e. catching the string 'Starting development server at' via regex and running the command `echo test` does not do anything.

Comment: I'm using iTerm 2.9. The feature you described seems the default setting. When I run 'git clone...', the tab title changes to 'git'; by default, the tab title is bash.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open 'Preference' (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
2. Select 'Appearance' Tab
3. Select '**Show current job name**' in field 'Windows & Tab Titles'

   *Base on iTerm 2.9*

Comment: Showing the current job name puts `(ssh)` in my tab title. I also don't want to do this manually every time I run `runserver`.

Comment: You needn't do it every time, as this is a global setting of iTerm2

Comment: Is there a way to show current running command when connected via ssh? Currently it actually just shows `(ssh)` in a tab title